# After restart Cassandra, Lucene index is not working

Tags: cassandra, lucene, cassandra-lucene-index

> Also check the error log file of the Cassandra and didn't find any warning or error in log file. Trying to rebuild the index but not working. Again need to insert for continuing Lucene index. But my other tables are working fine. Following my current table where I am facing the problem of this. currently partition key is the text field.

```
CREATE TABLE app_countries(
    country_name text,
    id timeuuid,
    "__v"
    timeuuid,
    continent_code text,
    country_calling_code text,
    created_at timestamp,
    currency text,
    image frozen < imageinfo > ,
    in_eu boolean,
    is_active boolean,
    is_deleted boolean,
    iso_code2 text,
    iso_code3 text,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    lucene text,
    sort_order int,
    timezone text,
    updated_at timestamp,
    utc_offset text,
    PRIMARY KEY(country_name, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(id DESC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {
    'keys': 'ALL',
    'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'
}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {
    'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'max_threshold': '32',
    'min_threshold': '4'
}
AND compression = {
    'chunk_length_in_kb': '64',
    'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'
}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX app_countries_id_idx ON app_countries(id);
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX app_countries_lucene_idx ON app_countries(lucene) USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'refresh_seconds': '1',
    'schema': '{"fields":{"id":{"type":"uuid"},"country_name":{"type":"string","case_sensitive":false},"currency":{"type":"string"},"country_calling_code":{"type":"string"},"is_active":{"type":"boolean"},"is_deleted":{"type":"boolean"},"sort_order":{"type":"integer"},"created_at":{"type":"date","pattern":"dd/MM/yyyy"}}}'
};
```

> Cassandra version: 3.11.3

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Are the index files gone? What do you get when you query using the index?

Comment: Problem is It doesn't return anything in the condition of query match after the restart of Cassandra. If I insert newly its return only new index, not previous data.

Comment: What version of Lucene index are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Cassandra Lucene index you are using but if you or anyone still facing the same problem it seems from the comment [here](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/261#issuecomment-276725716) that it is an issue in some older versions and it is [fixed](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/261#issuecomment-277017518) in newer versions, so check that the version you are using is a new version not suffering the issue and follow the [build steps](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/tree/branch-3.9#build-and-install) to produce the jar.